# Panels with items acting like a button

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, oop

I have some `Panel`'s and each `Panel` has a `PictureBox` and a `Label` in it.

```
public static void redPanel(Panel panel1)
{
   panel1.MouseEnter += new EventHandler((o, a) => panel1.BackColor = Color.Brown);
   panel1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler((o, a) => panel1.BackColor = Color.DarkRed);
   panel1.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler((o, a) => panel1.BackColor = Color.Firebrick);
   panel1.MouseLeave += new EventHandler((o, a) => panel1.BackColor = Color.Firebrick);
}
```

I made this code so the panel reacts to mouse hover and click ... but if I hover the `Label` or the `PictureBox` the `Panel` reverts to its original color. I want that the `Label` and the `PictureBox` to act exactly like the `Panel` (ex: If I click the `Label` I want that to count as a click on the `Panel`).

I want some code ... like `SourceControl` or something for the function from top to manage its own `Label` and `PicureBox`.

P.S: I tried to make another functions for `Label` and `PictureBox` but each `Panel` has different color so It means that I need to have about 23 lines of code just for labels ...

Comment: Just attach **same handler to all of them** (button, picture box and panel)...of course not using an anonymous method.

Comment: To simplify things, you could use a transparent(empty) pictureBox or something like this as an overlay over your panel and only handle the events of this 'overlay'. (To make this more reusable you could also write a custom control)

Comment: @user1567896 a transparent control won't even catch clicks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quick answer:** just attach the same handler to all of them.

```
public static void redPanel(Panel panel1)
{
    var mouseEnter = new EventHandler((o, a) => panel1.BackColor = Color.Brown);
    panel1.MouseEnter += mouseEnter;
    pictureBox1.MouseEnter += mouseEnter;
    label1.MouseEnter += mouseEnter;

    // And so on
}
```

**Better answer:** change your code, if it's a reusable component you'd better to create a `UserControl` with a `PictureBox` and a `Label`. From Designer then assign the same event handler to events generated from both of them (plus `UserControl` itself).

That said a button is much more than that (it has to react to keyboard events, can be focused, can be default button and so on). I'd prefer to derive from button to just add drawing features (a label and an image are very little code).